# Python variable with multiple inputs?

Tags: python-3.x

In my code according to the number the user has entered , it ask the user "Please enter the GTIN code for products needed".
So if the user initially enters 5 , it asks the question 5 times.
This means that I have multiple input for the variable "GTIN" , so at the end of my code I need to print out all the codes in a downward list but if I try to print GTIN , it will just paste the last input from the user.

My code :

```
while True:
itemsneeded = input("How many items do you need?")
if itemsneeded.isnumeric() and int(itemsneeded) <= 5:
    break
GTIN=''
count=0
while count<int(itemsneeded):
       GTIN=(input('Please enter all GTIN-8 for all items'))
       if GTIN.isnumeric() and len(GTIN)==8:
            Num0=int(GTIN[0])*3
            Num1=int(GTIN[1])
            Num2=int(GTIN[2])*3
            Num3=int(GTIN[3])
            Num4=int(GTIN[4])*3
            Num5=int(GTIN[5])
            Num6=int(GTIN[6])*3
            Num7=int(GTIN[7])
            total2=(Num0+Num1+Num2+Num3+Num4+Num5+Num6+Num7)
            if total2 % 10 == 0:
                print(GTIN)
                if GTIN in open('read_it.txt').read():
                    print('entered GTIN is valid')
                else:
                    print('The code entered is invalid')
                    print('Please renter this code')

            count+=1
        else:
            print("The entered GTIN-8 codes are incorrect")
            print(GTIN)
```

`
use code 
46389121 when testing and you are only allowed to enter max 5 items.

Comment: It's unclear what is happening, and what you expected instead. I would recommend breaking this code down into a few separate functions, e.g. one to take appropriate user input, one to process a single GTIN code and one to call the previous two at the appropriate times.

Comment: You could use a list to store the previous codes, something like `attempts.append(GTIN)` inside your loop.

Comment: So shall I store it as a list before or after the user enters the codes ?